# Compile Error: Invalid constructor syntax, name=value pairs can only be used for SObjects

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

**Apex Class:**

```
public class Flight {

    public String getFlight() {
        return null;
    }


        public Flight__c flights;
        public Flight__c del;
        public List < Flight__c > addFlightlist {get;set;}
        public List < Flight__c > delFlightlist {get;set;}
        public List < Flight__c > FlightList {get;set;}
        public Integer totalCount {get;set;}
        public Integer rowIndex {get;set;}
        public List < Flight__c > delContacts {get;set;}

        public Flight() {
                 FlightList = [Select id, TO__c, Return_Date__c,From__c,Depart__c,Flight_Name__c from Flight__c];
                totalCount = FlightList.size();
                delFlightlist = new List < Flight__c > ();
                delContacts = new List < Flight__c > ();
        }

  public PageReference cancel() {
        return null;
    }
        public void addRow() {
                addFlightlist = new List < flight__c > ();
             //FlightList.add(new Flight(FlightId = flights.Name));
               }

        public PageReference save() {
                upsert FlightList;
                delete delFlightlist;
                //return (new ApexPages.standardController (flights)).view();
                PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/flightedit_rowwise ');
                pageRef.setredirect(true);
               // pageRef.getParameters().put('id',account.);
                return pageRef;
        }
        public void deleteRow() {
                rowIndex = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex'));
                del = flightList.remove(rowIndex);
                delFlightlist.add(del);
        }
}
```

**Visualforce:**

```
<apex:page Controller="Flight" sidebar="false">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock title="Flights Details" id="pb">
      <apex:pageMessages />      
      <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!0}"/>
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="thetable" title="flight" var="f" value="{!Flightlist}">
          <apex:column headerValue="No." style="width:20px; text-align:center;" headerClass="centertext">
            <apex:outputText value="{0}" style="text-align:center;">
              <apex:param value="{!rowNumber+1}" />
            </apex:outputText>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Flight Name" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!f.Flight_Name__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="TO" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!f.TO__c}"/>     

          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="from" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!f.From__c}"/>
          </apex:column>

          <apex:column headerValue="Depart" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!f.Depart__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow}" reRender="pb">
              <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>
            <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber+1}"/>
          </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!addRow}" value="Add_Flight" reRender="pb"/>      
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>           
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Error Message:**

> Error: Flight Compile Error: Invalid constructor syntax, name=value pairs can only be used for SObjects at line 29 column 29

Answer (score 2):

Error message is descriptive enough, Your following code:

```
FlightList.add(new Flight(FlightId = flights.Name));
```

should be:

```
FlightList.add(new Flight__c(Flight_Name__c = flights.Name));
```

Comment: now getting this error:  System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!addRow}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page flightedit_rowwise: Class.Flight.addRow: line 29, column 1

Class.Flight.addRow: line 29, column 1

Comment: That's a different error, it says you need to handle exception properly in your code.